# How to fix this "Exception in Application start method"

Tags: java

Exception in Application start method
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: logs\06-10-2019 23-12-09 Log.txt.lck

I've tried deleting "target" file, but it did not help.

In MyLogger.java:

```
static public void setup() throws IOException {

        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);

        String time = LocalDateTime.now()
                .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss"));

        logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        fileTxt = new FileHandler("logs\\" + time.toString() + "Log.txt");
        fileHTML = new FileHandler("logs\\" + time.toString() + "Log.html");

        // create a TXT formatter
        formatterTxt = new SimpleFormatter();
        fileTxt.setFormatter(formatterTxt);
        logger.addHandler(fileTxt);

        // create an HTML formatter
        formatterHTML = new HtmlFormatter();
        fileHTML.setFormatter(formatterHTML);
        logger.addHandler(fileHTML);
    }
```

In Main.java:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        MyLogger.setup();

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com.mateusz.nawigacja.GUI/Scene.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setTitle("abc");
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(1024);
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(768);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: At first I would simply modify the pattern to remove the space from the file name.

Comment: done, but it changed nothing

Comment: What Java version do you use and what log4j version? And please try a folder that is definitely writable as a target path (e.g.: c:\\Temp)

Comment: I use 1.8 (java version "1.8.0_221"). How i can found information about log4j version? I tried different path, but it gives to me some another errors: javafx.fxml.LoadException: (...)classes/com.mateusz.nawigacja.gui/Drawer.fxml (...) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: and I know that this project should be working, becouse it's building all good at my mate laptop, so in my opinion its a configuration issue